# How to Run for each loop in template chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have a attribute in the form of array, and i want to iterate over it in Chef template ?

```
<% node['db2']['instance_username'].each do |device| -%> 
  <%= "/home/#{device}/sqllib/lib64" %>
<% end -%>
```

I'm doing like this but it is giving error.

Comment: you see that the formatting of your question is pretty bad?

Comment: Can you share more info, like error log?

Comment: What is your error?  That code looks pretty good to me.  Are you 100% sure that you have an array in that attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef Ruby loop over attributes in an .erb template file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235295/chef-ruby-loop-over-attributes-in-an-erb-template-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% 
node['db2']['instance_username'].each do |device| 
%> 
  /home/<%= device %>/sqllib/lib64
<% end %>
```

I'd rewrite it like this instead. If you are having an error try taking out the end hyphens out they are a rails construct and I'm not sure if they cross over well but it would help a lot if you posted the error you are having. Most likely instance username is not an array.