# Chef template loop ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have json file which import as environment file to chef,

```
    { 
    "mongodb": {
      "replicaset": {
        "nodes": [
          "test-mongo1:27017",
          "test-mongo2:27017"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

I chef cookbook template added as below to build the mongo connection string,

```
"mongo": {
    "url" : "mongodb://<% node['mongodb']['replicaset']['nodes'].each do |replica| -%>admin:123456@<%= replica %>/user_db1",
<% end %>
```

But output like below and not validating as JSON

```
"mongo": {
"url" : "mongodb://admin:123456@test-mongo1:27017/user_db1",
admin:123456@test-mongo2:27017/user_db1",
```

Expected Result:

```
"mongo": {
"url" : "mongodb://admin:123456@test-mongo1:27017/user_db1,admin:123456@test-mongo2:27017/user_db1",
```

Followed [How to Run for each loop in template chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600349/how-to-run-for-each-loop-in-template-chef), But my ruby isn't the best because I'm just starting out with all of this stuff. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Use `map` not `each`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, we can attempt to fix the loop so that only the necessary parts are included in the inner block:

```
"mongo": {
    "url" : "mongodb://<% node['mongodb']['replicaset']['nodes'].each do |replica| -%>admin:123456@<%= replica %>/user_db1,<% end %>",
```

This however still results in a problem: There is a trailing comma since we always add it after each iteration.

A better approach would thus be to first build a list of URLs and then join them with a comma to a single string. That way, there is only a comma added between elements. This should work instead:

```
"mongo": {
    "url" : "mongodb://<%= node['mongodb']['replicaset']['nodes'].map { |replica| "admin:123456@#{replica}/user_db1" }.join(",") %>",
```

Basically, what this code does is the following:

```
output = ""

output << "\"mongo\": {\n"
output << "    \"url\" : \"mongodb://"
urls = node['mongodb']['replicaset']['nodes'].map do |replica|
  output << "admin:123456@"
  output << replica
  output << "/user_db1"
end
output << urls.join(", ")
output << "\","
```

Here, `output` represents the output of the ERB template. In the actual ERB implementation, there is a bit more logic involved, but the basic logic works similar to that.

When doing this in an actual cookbook, usually a better approach is to build the URLs in your recipe already and pass them to your template prebuild:

In `recipes/default.rb`:

```
urls = node['mongodb']['replicaset']['nodes'].map do |replica| 
  "admin:123456@#{replica}/user_db1"
end

template '/path/to/mongo.json' do
  source 'my_template.json.erb'
  variables mongo_urls: urls
end
```

In `templates/default/my_template.json.erb`:

```
"mongo": {
    "url" : "mongodb://<%= @mongo_urls.join(",") %>",
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me. but the output still not as expected.
`"url" : "mongodb://admin:123456@test-mongo1:27017/user_db1admin:123456@test-mongo2:27017/user_db1",`
It's not separating by comma.

Comment: resolved, thanks for the help :), will look into prebuild and including it to the template.